# USB Boot graphics corrupted on Macbook. UEFI mode?

Tags: boot, usb, graphics, macbook, screen-corruption

I'm trying to run 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 off my USB stick on my Macbook Pro. USB stick is fine AFAIK, but when it boots I get corrupt graphics after the boot menu, so can only see random blocks of colour.

Here's what I did: boot whilst holding Option/Alt. Choose the "EFI Boot" USB icon instead of my normal HDD. It then flashes up saying something very quickly, then gives me the Ubuntu menu where I can try Ubuntu without installing, Install it, or Check the disk for defects. If I choose "Try without installing" the screen goes black for 10 secs or so, then gives me the corrupt bollocks.

I assume it's obviously something to do with the graphics driver. Is there anything I can poke with or edit on the USB stick so it'll force it to run from the USB stick in some kinda sensible/lower performance graphics mode? I'm guessing it's getting over excited and trying to choose some driver that doesn't work with either my Intel HD graphics or the discrete nVidia 330M.

Whilst I'm asking, I don't suppose any Macuntu users out there know whether the "EFI Boot" icon implies it's trying to boot UEFI mode (which Apple's EFI may not fully support) instead of seeing it as a "Windows" disk and running with BIOS emulation?

Answer (score 0):

When you see the little pictures at the bottom like a man and a keyboard, press F6 and then using the arrow keys and enter, check Nomodeset. Then, continue to boot. Once you install, you can enable nomodeset by at the grub menu, pressing <kbd>e</kbd> and adding `nomdeset` to the long line that usually has `quiet splash` in it. Then, use Alt_F2 to run `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. Add `nomodeset` to the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`(but make sure it is inside the quotes), save, and open a terminal. Run `sudo update-grub`.

Sorry about lack of screenshots.